# Is there a way to determine what CGLFlushDrawable is doing to the back buffer?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, buffer, wgl

According to Apple's documentation, `CGLFlushDrawable` or it's Cocoa equivalent `flushBuffer` may behave in couple different ways. Normally for a windowed application the contents of a back buffer are copied to the visible buffer like it's stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGLFlushDrawable):

> **CGLFlushDrawable**
>
> Copies the back buffer of a double-buffered context to the front buffer.

I assume the contents of the drawing buffer are left untouched (see question 1.). Even if I'm wrong, it can be assured by passing the `kCGLPFABackingStore` attribute to `CGLChoosePixelFormat`.

But further reading reaveals, that under some circumstances the buffers may be swapped rather than copying being performed:

> If the backing store attribute is set to false, the buffers can be exchanged rather than copied. This is often the case in full-screen mode.

And also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html) states

> When there is no content above your full-screen window, Mac OS X automatically attempts to optimize this context’s performance. For example, when your application calls `flushBuffer` on the `NSOpenGLContext` object, the system may swap the buffers rather than copying the contents of the back buffer to the front buffer. (...) Because the system may choose to swap the buffers rather than copy them, your application must completely redraw the scene after every call to `flushBuffer`.

And here go my questions:

1. If the back buffer is copied, is it guaranteed, that it's contents are preserved even without the backing store attribute?
2. If the bufferse are swapped, does the back buffer get contents of the front buffer, or is it undefined so it could as well get random stuff?
3. The system *may* choose to swap buffers, but is there any way to determine if it actually  *did* choose to do so?
4. In any of those cases, is there a way to determine if the buffer was preserved, exchanged with the front buffer or got messed up?

Also any information on how it is made in WGL, GLX or EGL would be appreciated. I particulary need the answer to the question 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it's not guaranteed.
2. It might be random.
3. No, I don't believe so.
4. No. If you don't specify `kCGLPFABackingStore` or `NSOpenGLPFABackingStore`, then you can't make any assumptions about the contents of the back buffer, which is why the docs say you must redraw from scratch for every frame.

I'm not sure what you're asking about WGL, GLX, and EGL.

Comment: 2. Wouldn't then using the term _swapping_ be misleading?

Also I edited my question specifying what I expect to know about WGL, GLX and EGL.

Comment: It could be swapping (or, if you prefer, switching) the back buffer into the front (without a copy operation) and yet not swapping/switching the front buffer to the back. The new back buffer may come from a pool or be a new, uninitialized buffer. It you were misled, then it may be misleading. ;)